# Presto query engine with Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure-data-lake, presto, query-engine

I have a requirement to deploy a presto server which can help me query data stored in ADLS in Avro file formats. 
I have gone through [this tutorial](https://github.com/arsenvlad/docker-presto-adls-wasb) and it seems that the Hive is used as a catalogue/connector in presto to query from ADLS. Can I bypass Hive and have any connector to extract data from ADLS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I bypass Hive and have any connector to extract data from ADLS?

No.

Hive here plays two roles here:

- storage for metadata. It contains information like:

  - schema and table name
  - columns
  - data format
  - data location
- execution

  - it is capable to read data from (HDFS) distributed file systems (like HDFS, S3, ADLS)
  - it tells how execution can be distributed.

Comment: Thanks for this crucial information. If I have some data in ADLS which is not coming through Hive(meaning metastore for this data wont be there) then how can I query that data using Presto?

Comment: You need to create an external table with location that would point that data.

Comment: So if i know the location of data, then I can use select * from hive.default.LOCATION without any schema, Right?